# How to hide the Fields with Null Value while looping the array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have some values stored in Database which are pulled from a form in the website.. Sometimes some fields may be NULL value or empty..

When I print my values using PHP json encode.. It prints all the values in an array..

I successfully get that info in my AngularJS Factory but when i try to display the values using ng-Repeat it also takes the null value..

What I want to do is hide the NULL values altogether when looping..

The image that is not displayed is the ones that are Null value ..I want to hide it altogether..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simple use ng-show on your image tag:-
For example

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <strong ng-show="post.tag!=null">{{post.tag}}</strong>   //You use <img ng-show="image!=null" src="./."></img>
        </div>
```

And data in posts is:

```
$scope.posts = [{id: 1, tag: 'tech'},
                    {id: 9, tag: null}, 
                    {id: 4, tag: 'sports'}, 
                    {id: 2, tag: null}];
```

Result:-

tech

sports

Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/66n6axpx/

Comment: Now it doesnt show the image but it does leave empty white space because the div is repeated without no image in it.. I believe if there is any filter that could skip repeating the null data..

Comment: Yup did by Applying ng-show to the repeat div and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

All the current answers suggest directly specifying in your HTML code. However, that is not a correct solution.

The cleanest way to do this is to create your own filter - that way, in the future, if you have another requirement which does not require the image to show if (for example) the image is of type png, then you can simply add the logic inside the filter without cluttering your HTML. Also, this approach does not even add the image to the DOM - using `ng-show` adds the element to the DOM but hides it - not a good solution for a large data.

So, in your case, the best practice is to create a filter function.
If your HTML code is -

```
<div data-ng-repeat="image in images | filter:hideImage"></div>
```

then your controller function will be

```
$scope.hideImage = function (image) {
    //Function will be called for each image
    //Function returns true or false
    //false - don't add image to DOM (actually, don't make image part of images)
    //true - add image to DOM
    if (image) {
        //image exists.
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Agree. Filter is a better solution in this case.

Comment: i was searching for a basic work around.. Was about to ask this question and you replied it.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ChanX Did you put a console statement and check if your function is called at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img ng-show="!image.tag" />` to hide the element if the tag is undefined or null.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. Will follow both of you guys suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented my own filter because the array was taking an array inside it.. I have to manually map it out using jQuery and then loop through gain..
Below is the filter code that I used:

```
diary.filter('TextFilter', function () {
    return function (Notes) {
        var filtered = [];
        for (i = 0; i < Notes.length; i++)
        {
            var note = Notes[i];
            if (note.text_notes != ''){
                filtered.push(note);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
});
```